# Андрій Первозванний чи Андрій Первозваний?

Tags: власні-назви, прикметники, подвоєння

Чи треба вживати подвоєння `-нн-` у слові *«Андрій Первозва**нн**ий»*?

- Російсько-український словник за ред. А. Кримського:
  Первозва́нный – первозва́ний: *Андрі́й Первозва́ний*
- Словник-довідник Жайворонка "Велика чи мала літера?" подвоєння не містить:
  *Первозваний (Андрій)*

З точки зору правопису, другий компонент складного слова — *-званий* — має дієприкметникове походження, що унеможливлює подвоєння (адже за правописом, українські дієприкметники не мають такого суфіксального подвоєння).

З іншого боку, є слова з подвоєнням.

За матеріалами підручнику «Український правопис» за ред. О. А. Дітель ([PDF](http://lib.pu.if.ua/elib/local/sk675253.pdf), стор. 22), я бачу наступні варіанти:

- Буква `н` **подвоюється**

  1. У наголошених суфіксах `-енн-`, `-анн-`:

     - у прикметниках, які вказують на більшу, ніж звичайна, чи **найбільшу міру якості**: *страшенний, здоровенний, височенний, нескінченний, невблаганний, несказанний, нездійсненний, незліченний, нездоланний, недоторканний*;
     - у прикметниках-**старослов'янізмах**: *благословенний, блаженний, мерзенний, огненний, окаянний, священний, спасений*, а також: *божественний*.
  2. у словах *старанний, притаманний, захланний, численний* <sub>(я так розумію, це слова-винятки)</sub>
- Буква `н` **не подвоюється**

  1. у прикметниках, які не вказують на більшу, ніж звичайна, міру якості: *нескінчений, нездоланий, шалений, скажений, навіжений*
  2. в дієприкметниках: *нежданий, довгожданий, жаданий, вихований, з'єднаний, придбаний, виїжджений, сповнений*.

Тоді виникає питання: до якої з вищенаведених груп належить *«первозван(нн)ий»*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67357/discussion-on-question-by-bytebuster-----).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Первозваний*** - складний дієприкметник, а дієприкметник [***званий***](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvanyj), як і всі дієприкметники, не має подвоєння приголосних у суфіксах згідно з [правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#prudie) (§ 23. Прикметникові та дієприкметникові суфікси).

> **`-АНН(ИЙ), -ЕНН(ИЙ), -АН(ИЙ), -ЕН(ИЙ)`**
>
> 2. Прикметникові суфікси **`-анн(ий), -енн(ий)`**, які вживаються для підкреслення найвищої міри ознаки, пишуться з двома **`н`**:
>      *невблаганний, нездоланний, неоціненний, несказанний, нескінченний, страшенний*; але: *жаданий*. Подібні прикметники завжди мають наголос
>      на суфіксі, що відрізняє їх від дієприкметників, утворених від
>      дієслівних коренів за допомогою суфіксів -**`ан(ий), -ен(ий)`**:
>      *бажаний, незлічений, неоцінений, неподоланий, несказаний, нескінчений*.

Конкретний приклад пояснює мовознавець А.Венцковський, [аналізуючи помилки в тестах ЗНО від 2008 року](http://www.personal-plus.net/308/4445.html):

> Варіант 8, текст (с. 128–129): Андрій Первозванний (треба:
>   Первозваний). Другий компонент (...званий) складного слова
>   «первозваний» має дієприкметникове походження, що внеможливлює
>   подвоєння (-нн-) у принципі: жодний український дієприкметник не має
>   такого (суфіксального) подвоєння. Зрозуміло, що й уживання слова
>   «первозваний» у функції власної назви не заперечує цієї орфограми.

І вже текст минулорічного [Радіодиктанту національної єдності](http://www.nrcu.gov.ua/Dyktant) містить цей антропонім з правильною орфографією.